# Cast substring to int only for numeric values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query :

```
SUBSTRING (
    dbo.Table.RNumber,
    1,
    CHARINDEX(
        '+',
        dbo.Table.RNumber
    ) - 1
) AS RoomNumber,
SUBSTRING (
    dbo.Table.R.Number,
    CHARINDEX(
        '+',
        dbo.Table.R.Number
    ) + 1,
    LEN(
        dbo.Table.R.Number
    )
) AS HallNumber,
```

My Table RNumber is mostly like 2+3 or 3+5, but sometimes it is like x+5 or y+0. I want to convert fields to int, but I want to convert strings like "x" or "y" to 0. I googled it but I couldn't find a solution. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Kindly provide sample data and table schema

Comment: @viki888 I provided sample data, dbo.Table.RNumber is string like `1+2` or `x+5` I want to get numeric values and if there is no numeric value, it will be 0. That's all

Comment: I wonder if you could use dynamic sql and have the parser interpret your strings to values.   SELECT (5+3) as FinalValue   for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use case statement try this

**Edited to use isnumeric() method**

```
CASE 
    WHEN isnumeric(SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.RNumber,1,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) - 1)) = 1
        THEN SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.RNumber,1,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) - 1) 
    else 0 
end AS RoomNumber,
CASE 
    WHEN isnumeric(SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.R.Number,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) + 1,LEN(dbo.Table.R.Number))) = 1
        THEN SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.R.Number,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) + 1,LEN(dbo.Table.R.Number)) 
    else 0 
end AS HallNumber,
```

Hope this should solve your problem

Comment: Is there an option using IsNumeric method for this? My boss didn't like regular expressions.

Comment: I have modified to use isnumeric() function

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use ParseName() and Try_Convert()

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeField varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2+3'),('3+5'),('x+5'),('y+0')

Select *
      ,RoomNumber = IsNull(Try_Convert(int,ParseName(Replace(SomeField,'+','.'),2)),0)
      ,HallNumber = IsNull(Try_Convert(int,ParseName(Replace(SomeField,'+','.'),1)),0)
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
SomeField   RoomNumber  HallNumber
2+3         2           3
3+5         3           5
x+5         0           5
y+0         0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

For versions prior to 2012, you can do it like this:

```
CASE 
WHEN NOT columnName like '%[^0-9]%' -- Contains no non-digits
AND columnName like '%[0-9]%' -- contains at least one digit
THEN CAST(columnName as INT) ELSE NULL 
END
```

(Note that this will reject negative numbers, but you can easily adapt it if you need to support them)

Alternatively using `IsNumeric`, you must first cast to `float` because `Isnumeric` accepts some strings that `Cast(EXPRESSION as INT)` does not accept:

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(columnName)=1 
THEN CAST(CAST(columnName as float) as int) END
```

Comment: Is there an option using IsNumeric method for this? My boss didn't like regular expressions.

Comment: IsNumeric will say yes to e.g. "1e-10" but CAST won't like it. THese are not full regex, they are "patterns". performance is very good.

Comment: I would be really glad if you provide IsNumeric version... Thank you very much.